# link to other system issue number in gerrit code review page based on commit message

Tags: gerrit

I used to write commit message to connect issue system like `issue #9548, redmine start page is fixed`, and wonder whether it can be written in hook or plugin in gerrit system.

So in the code review page, the **issue #9548** can be automatically show the http link to my issues system (like redmine): => `issue`[#9548](http://www.redmine.org/issues/),`redmine start page is fixed`

It will be easily for code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In your Gerrit configuration, you have to provide a regex expression for the string in the commit message and the link to your bugtracker with wildcards. See the [Gerrit documentation](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.2.1/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_commentlink_a_section_commentlink). For your example, you would have a regex like (issue\s+#?)(\d+)

Answer (score 4):

If you use Jira and have your Jira case number first in the commit message, add the following to gerrit.config to get links when viewing change sets:

```
[commentlink "jira"]
    match = "^([A-Z]*-[0-9]*)"
    link = http://jira/browse/$1
```

Some supported commit message formats (paste into [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test):

- PRJ-123: This is my commit message
- ABC-123 - Something: Yes yes
- PROJ-123
- ABCD-123 - Message

For more examples, see the [Gerrit documentation on Section commentlink](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#commentlink)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can turn the issue tag into a link in Gerrit.  Look at the commentlink configuration - http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.2.0/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_commentlink_a_section_commentlink